# Rename Document Set that has declared documets

Tags: 2010, document-set, rename

In a 2010 SharePoint site, we would like to rename a number of document sets. The problem is that when the documents are already declared, it becomes a tedious mess that takes a very long time. We have to change the names of around 250 documents sets we would like to change.

Could we do this with powershell? Any comments or suggestions on how to solve this issue would be appreciated.